# Wording of migration closure

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, migration

When we close a question through migration to another SE site, it gets a box looking like

[image]

The blue text to math.stackexchange.com is a link pointing to the newly created clone at the other end of the migration, but it is not quite clear that this is so.

> Could we make it more explicit that it is a link to the new copy?

Comment: Most users never see that link anyway, non-mods are redirected automatically to the migrated copy of the question.

Comment: @MadScientist: Not really *never*, but only when they click on the link to MathOverflow below the migrated question on Math.SE.

Comment: @StefanKohl while I upvoted your comment as it adds something relevant, I still feel the need to point out that it seems true that most users never see it (though they could see it if they want, though in this case it does not seem very relevant to have the link).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not quite sure what we could do to make that any more explicit, maybe add a ***→*** to the right of the link? Make 'Migrated' the link instead? But as pointed out in comments:

- Typically, moderators are the only people to see the link, as they need to be able to access the original question in cases where a migration needs to be reversed and cleared
- The only non-moderators that would see the question are those coming *from* the migrated question on the destination site.

I really don't see that it's worth it, since the only people seeing the link either (1) *know* where it leads, or (2) *have been* where it leads. It's not a *bad* idea, but in the absence of more confusion about where it goes, I don't think the change would pass the cost to benefit  test. Remember, the engine is now almost fully localized, so every string (or bit of text) must also be updated in translations.